# php wordpress processing inside the hook and synchronizing the value to the variable outside the hook

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

what I want is that I have a special taxonomy and get_terms does not work without it being loaded, naturally the only way I can get it is to hook up to "init". But when this is the case, I will have to repeat this. I do not want this.

As you can see in the code below, I am doing the operation in init and trying to transfer it to "$ new_array". How can I do it?

```php
    protected function get_reactions()
    {
        $new_array = array();
        
        add_action( 'init', function() use ( &$new_array ) {
            $reactions = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'bp_reaction',
                'hide_empty' => false
            ));
    
            foreach ( $reactions as $value ) {
                $priority = get_option( 'taxonomy_'.$value->term_id.'_priority' );
                $image    = get_option( 'taxonomy_'.$value->term_id.'_image' );
                $new_array[$priority] = (object) array(
                    'id'       => $value->term_id,
                    'priority' => $priority,
                    'slug'     => $value->slug,
                    'name'     => $value->name,
                    'image'    => $image
                );
            }
        }, 9 );

        // Sort from largest to small
        krsort( $new_array );

        return $new_array;
    }
```

Comment: `$new_array = $reactions;` maybe?

Comment: I tried both as a parameter and as a use, but I couldn't get a result!

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense, it's kind of a conflict with the whole purpose of a hook. Can't you use the get_terms without the "init" hook? Or maybe hook the get_recations functions in "init"?

Comment: I don't know WP but in principle https://3v4l.org/8ImpN

Comment: Hello, I created a custom taxonomy, naturally it says if I do not use init, there is no such taxonomy. So I need to use get_termsi after the register_taxonomy event, it is by connecting it to hooks like init wp_loaded or after_theme_setup.

Comment: I did an operation in a custom class and tried to pass it to the class variable, but still failed!

Comment: Somewhere you do this `$result = $obj->get_reactions();`???

Comment: @AbraCadaver https://prnt.sc/wkgwkr https://prnt.sc/wkgwup I run it after the register event, but it still returns empty. It's ridiculous. I couldn't understand!